# how to read width and height in nexus 7?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

i am trying to read the width and height of a nexus 7 2013 device, using the fallowing js code:

```
 while (!(width && height)){
              //  alert("if this msg shows more then once - the height or width has been falsly read as 0");
                width =  e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth || w.innerWidth;
                height = e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight || w.innerHeight;
            }
```

it works fine on all devices, but the nexus 7 2013. Only on this device, it sometimes reads it's width as 1920, and sometimes as 960.

can anyone please help me understand why it happens and how to overcome this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

```
 <script>
 var y=screen.availHeight;
 var x=screen.availWidth;
 alert("Your resolution is "+x+" X "+y);
 </script>
```

The problem you are getting sometimes happens when the window focuses - I think